# Dynamic Translation on Fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation, google-translate

Well pretty straight-forward Question.

Client needs -

(i) `Lang. Translation` based on `User`

(ii) Application must support any language and **it should be totally dynamic.**

*(without any pre-hand translations)*

How could we translate value without a key, i'm familiar with [i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n)

It must translate all `labels` in the application as well as `items` that are fetched `tables`.

Is this even possible? Is there any 3rd party apps that will translate complete page?

I have heard about [google + translate](https://developers.google.com/translate) can this be used? any reviews?

Regards.